# HTML META XML DATA Inclusion

Tags: xml, rss, standards, meta

I was thinking (Danger), that most webpages are "Good Content" surrounded by "Rubbish", adverts, upsells etc.  The search engines know this, they see the rubbish and extract the information they want, but I was a thinking.... What if I could include an XML/RSS feed referenced in the META which included just that Good Content, perfectly formed.

```
<title>Acne Commercial Soap</title>
<url>http://acne.no/commercial-soap/</url>
<description/>etc
<image/>etc
<related-products>
 <title>Acne Commercial Soap Brush</title>
 <url>http://acne.no/commercial-soap-brush/</url> 
 <description/>etc
 <image/>etc
</related-products>
```

Is there already a standard in place for such a thing?  Referencing the core content of the page in the page?  Is am I just insaine?

Answer (score 1):

[RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/) and [Microformats](http://microformats.org/) are both intended to achieve this goal (though not in the fashion you describe)

Comment: Any evidence to support if this is worth the effort?

Comment: @Stuart, that depends on what it is that you want.  It won't improve your ranking in Google, but it will enable google to display rich snippets in search results.

Comment: Then that answers my question, thanks Paul.  The system seems a little infant in it explaination.